# Shopify Section Schema is not Showing in the Admin

Tags: schema, shopify, sections

I am working on a custom Shopify theme and I got stuck here and I don't know the reason behind it. This schema is not showing up at all. I have 9 other schemas and they all work find.
Your help is really appreciated if you can figure out what is wrong and why not showing up in the front admin panel in order to add content.

Thanks;

```
{% schema %}
        {
            "name": "product FAQ page",
            "settings": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "id": "faq",
                    "label": "Product",
                    "default": "content"
                }
            ]
        }

    {% endschema %}
```

Comment: Can you share the whole contents of your schema code?

Answer (score 1):

The schema itself looks normal, and if Shopify allows you to save that file in the theme editor it means that Shopify considers your schema valid.  If the settings are not showing up in your theme-customization admin panel, it *probably* means that Shopify doesn't think that the above section is relevant to the page you're looking at in the theme customizer.

Two things to check:

- Have you remembered to include your section somewhere in your site? (Using `{% section 'my-section-name' %}`, double-checking for typos)
- When trying to edit your settings for the section, are you currently looking at a page that includes that section?

I'm assuming that you're not expecting this to appear as a section that you can add dynamically to the Index page - but if you are making a dynamically-included section, remember that you need to include at least one preset in the schema data (See https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/sections#static-and-dynamic-sections for Shopify's documentation on dynamic sections)

Comment: Checking the code-editor in Shopify is a good suggestion. Countless times now I've been utterly confused why Shopify is serving the wrong file and it's all because it silently rejects invalid Liquid files.

Comment: This happened to me, my because the default value I was setting wasn't a valid value. The json was valid, so it would upload from the local editor when using the cli, but no errors showed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add dynamic sections you should include a preset configuration so that it appears on the "add sections" editor

```
{% schema %}
    {
        "name": "product FAQ page",
        "settings": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "id": "faq",
                "label": "Product",
                "default": "content"
            }
        ],
        "presets": [
            {
                "name": "section name",
                "category": "custom section"
            }
        ]
    }

{% endschema %}
```

for the static section, you could simply add {% section 'my-file-name' %}

Answer (score 0):

```
    You just need to set the preset for the same 
    
    {% schema %}
        {
            "name": "product FAQ page",
            "settings": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "id": "faq",
                    "label": "Product",
                    "default": "content"
                }
            ],
            "presets": [
                {
                    "name": {
                           "en": "Add FAQ Section"        
                     }
                }
            ]
        }
    
    {% endschema %}
```

Note: Go to the customize theme option , from left side options you will find the button "Add Section" click on that you will have the section "Add FAQ Section" click on that it will be there on the page.